# Keep scattered images from going outside of container div

Tags: javascript, html

Hoping somebody can help. I have recently finished a degree in computing where one of my modules was to create a website. I decided to create a website for my friends parents so once the course was finished I would actually have something I could use.

Anyway one of the pages is a gallery. It uses javascript to scatter images randomly across the page. Problem is I needed to keep the images contained so that they didnt appear onto of other items on my page (header for instance).

We didnt study javascript on the course as this module was replace so any code is just what I have found on the internet....

HTML:

```
<div id="imageBlock" style="height:1300px; width:1000px;">
        <a href="img/DUDLEY.jpg" title="Dudley aged ??"><img src="img/DUDLEY.jpg" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies6.jpg"><img src="img/puppies6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img/Ruben.jpg" title="Ruben aged ???"><img src="img/Ruben.jpg" /></a>
<a href="img/wendy.jpg" title="Wendy aged ??"><img src="img/wendy.jpg" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies4.jpg"><img src="img/puppies4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies7.jpg"><img src="img/puppies7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies2.jpg"><img src="img/puppies2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img/brutus.jpg" title="Brutus aged ??"><img src="img/brutus.jpg" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies3.jpg"><img src="img/puppies3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img/puppies5.jpg"><img src="img/puppies5.jpg" alt="" /></a>    
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var zindexnr = 1;
    var container = $('#imageBlock');
    $("img").draggable({
        containment: container,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            zindexnr++;
            var cssObj = { 'z-index' : zindexnr };
            $(this).css(cssObj);
        }
    });

$(function() {
        $('#imageBlock a').lightBox();
    });

//Report the X & Y co-ords
$('#imageBlock img').hover(function()
{
    thisX = $(this).css('left')
    thisY = $(this).css('top')

    $('#currentX span').text(thisX);
    $('#currentY span').text(thisY);

})

//Initialise everything
var screenX = 1000, screenY = 750;
var xPos = 0, yPos = 0;

var xCounter=0, yCounter = 0;

var incrementalDelay = 0;

var origImageWidth = 0, origImageHeight = 0
var newImageWidth = 0, newImageHeight = 0

var numImages = $('#imageBlock img').length;  //20

xDivAmount = screenX / numImages;  // 1000/20 = 50
yDivAmount = screenY / numImages;  // 800/20 = 40

//create the position arrays
var posXArray = new Array;
var posYArray = new Array;

//Pre-populate the array
for (i=0; i<numImages; i++) //20 loops
{
    posXArray[i] = xCounter;  //0 on 1st run
    xCounter += xDivAmount;   //+50

    posYArray[i] = yCounter;  //0 on 1st run
    yCounter += yDivAmount;   //+40
}

$('#imageBlock img').each(function(index)
{
    origImageWidth = $(this).width();  //get the full width and height of each image
    origImageHeight = $(this).height();

    percentMultiply = (Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1)/10  //random percentage multiplier (up to 40%)

    //newImageWidth = Math.floor(origImageWidth * percentMultiply);   //calculate new sizes
    //newImageHeight = Math.floor(origImageHeight * percentMultiply);

    newImageWidth = Math.floor(origImageWidth * 0.6);   //hard code new sizes
    newImageHeight = Math.floor(origImageHeight * 0.6);

    $(this).css({'width':newImageWidth, 'height':newImageHeight})  //apply new calculated sizes


    rotation = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)-15+'deg'; //random rotation
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform' , 'rotate('+rotation+')'); //apply rotation
    $(this).css('-moz-transform' , 'rotate('+rotation+')');

    randX = Math.floor(Math.random()*posXArray.length)  //Create random num 1 - array length
    randY = Math.floor(Math.random()*posYArray.length)

    //Output the content of the array - purely for DEV reasons
    for (i=0; i<posXArray.length; i++)
    {
        xOut=posXArray[i]
        yOut=posYArray[i]
        console.log('X:['+i+'] '+xOut+' Y:['+i+'] '+yOut)
    }

    console.log('Array pos for X: '+randX)
    console.log('Array pos for Y: '+randY)

    xPos = posXArray[randX]; //position = value at random location
    yPos = posYArray[randY];

    console.log('X: '+xPos)
    console.log('Y: '+yPos)

    console.log('')

    //remove the array values for chosen position
    posXArray.splice(randX, 1)
    posYArray.splice(randY, 1)


    //animate to position
    $(this).delay(incrementalDelay).animate({'left':xPos,'top':yPos}, 2000)
    //$(this).animate({'left':xPos,'top':yPos}, 1200)

    incrementalDelay +=80  //increment time delay for each loop

})

});

$(window).load(function ()
{

});
```